# spring-security xml configuration

Tags: java, spring

I have the following spring-security.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-Instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-4.2.xsd">

    <http>
        <intercept-url pattern="/course*" access="ROLE_USER"/>
    </http>

    <authentication-manager>
        <authentication-provider>
            <user-service>
                <user name="testuser" password="testpw" authorities="ROLE_USER"/>
            </user-service>
        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>


</beans:beans>
```

When I start tomcat, I get the following error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 8 in XML document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-security.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 8; columnNumber: 78; cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'beans:beans'.
```

I have tried a few different combinations of schemaLocation inclusions/exclusions. Can anyone see what I may be missing?

Comment: Why you should not move to Java Config configuration for Spring security?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `beans:beans` you should use `b:beans`

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<beans  xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.1.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-4.1.xsd">

<!-- Other configuration -->

</beans>
```